# Apply and Lambda function - ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I'm trying to create a new column dividing 'ID' values by 219 if 'Gender' is 'Female and 393 if 'Gender is 'Male' by using Apply and Lambda functions. First, I tried to use 'Gender' column which has categorical variables which didn't work. so I created a binary column based on 'Gender' assigning 0 to 'Female 1 to 'Male' and use that column, but didn't work.

I'm still getting the value error like this:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

my code is

```
by_label_out_degree[NormID] = by_label_out_degree.apply(lambda row: row['ID']/ 219 if row['Gender2'] == 0 else row['ID']/ 393,axis=1)
```

I'm adding my code again! Thank you for your help!!

```
values = [
[42785,428855,'Energy','Female'],
[43432,428686,'Trust','Male'],
[43432,428686,'Career','Male'],
[43432,428686,'Personal','Male'],
[43432,428634,'Trust','Female']
]
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(values, columns =['ID','Target','Label','Gender'])
new_df = df.groupby(['Gender','Label']).ID.count().reset_index()
new_df['Gender2'] = new_df.Gender.map({'Female':0,'Male':1})
new_df['NormID'] = new_df.apply(lambda row: row['ID']/219 if row['Gender2'] == 0 else row['ID']/393, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Please **do not post images of data or links to data** Post the code an data as *formatted text* always provide a [mcve]. see the [help] and [ask]

Answer (score 2):

#### Fix

The use of column `Gender` works nice

```
values = [
    ['Female', 'Access', 96],
    ['Female', 'Career', 165],
    ['Male', 'Access', 236],
    ['Male', 'Energy', 445]
]
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['Gender', 'Label', 'ID'])
df['newcol'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['ID'] / 219 if row['Gender'] == 'Female' else row['ID'] / 393, axis=1)
print(df)

   Gender   Label   ID    newcol
0  Female  Access   96  0.438356
1  Female  Career  165  0.753425
2    Male  Access  236  0.600509
3    Male  Energy  445  1.132316
```

#### Better

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

values = [['Female', 'Access', 96], ['Female', 'Career', 165],
          ['Male', 'Access', 236], ['Male', 'Energy', 445]]
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['Gender', 'Label', 'ID'])
df['newcol'] = np.where(df['Gender'] == 'Female', df['ID'] / 219, df['ID'] / 393)
print(df)
```

Comment: But mine still doesn't work... I think it's because my dataframe was created from the groupby operation? Do I have to change my dataframe into a normal dataframe? But when I did type(mydataframe), it gave me this: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. confused... I will keep trying!! anyways! Thank you so much for your help on not just answering my question but also how to post my questions properly!!!!! This is my first time posting a question on Stack overflow and I already learned a lot!!

Comment: @Data_Yoda can you show the code you used to create the Gender2 column , and the code since the creation of the dataframe ? edit your initial post and add that please, I'll take a look

Comment: When I construct a reduced version of my code, I found that I didn't use quotation mark for adding a new column like this: df[newcol]! Thank you so much for your help, azro!!

Comment: @ azro quick question! why using numpy.where is better in this case? Is is related to execution speed?